# PonyORM orphaned items when clearing a set that defines one-to-many relation

Tags: ponyorm

I have a basic relation defined as follows:
   db = Database('sqlite', 'test_db.sqlite', create_db=True)

```
class WOEID(db.Entity):
    woeid      = PrimaryKey(int)
    iso        = Optional(str)
    name       = Required(str)
    language   = Optional(str)
    place_type = Required(str)
    parent_id  = Required(int)
    trends     = Set('Trend')
    ancestry   = Optional(str)

class Trend(db.Entity):
    woeid                = Required(int)
    events               = Optional(str)
    name                 = Required(str)
    promoted_content     = Optional(str)
    query                = Required(str)
    url                  = Required(str)
    location             = Optional(WOEID)

db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```

Now, I add some items to WOEID.trends within a function decorated with @db_session. This works as expected.
Now I try to update WOEID.trends by first reading an object using

```
 location = WOEID.get(woeid = some_woeid)
```

later on I issue

```
location.trends.clear()
```

to delete old entries and I add new items to the trends set.

In the generated Trends table after this operation I have the items added, but previous items (cleared from the set) are not deleted, they stay in the database with 'location' field nulled (they are dereferenced I guess).

How should I perform the operation outlined above to get read of orphaned items?

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of one-to-many relationships in PonyORM. The first kind of relationship is when one end of relationship is `Set` and the other end of relationship is `Required`. In that case when you remove an item from the collection this item will be deleted. For example we can define two entities `Article` and `Comment` in the following way:

```py
class Article(db.Entity):
    author = Required(User)
    text = Required(str)
    comments = Set('Comment')

class Comment(db.Entity):
    author = Required(User)
    text = Required(str)
    article = Required(Article)
```

In that case, when you perform `article.comments.clear()` all comment will be deleted, because the `Comment.article` attribute is required and a comment cannot exist without an article.

The other kind of relationship is where `Comment.article` attribute is defined as `Optional`:

```py
class Comment(db.Entity):
    author = Required(User)
    text = Required(str)
    article = Optional(Article)
```

In that case a comment can exist without any article, and when you remove the comment from the `Article.comments` collection it remains in the database, but the `Comment.article` attribute value is set to `NULL`.

You can find orphaned items by executing the following query:

```py
select(c for c in Comment if c.article is None)
```

or, equivalently

```py
Comment.select(lambda c: c.article is None)
```

In some cases it may be desirable to define attribute as `Optional`, but perform cascade delete on removing item from the collection. In order to do this, you can specify `cascade_delete` option for the `Set` attribute:

```py
class Article(db.Entity):
    author = Required(User)
    text = Required(str)
    comments = Set('Comment', cascade_delete=True)

class Comment(db.Entity):
    author = Required(User)
    text = Required(str)
    article = Optional(Article)
```

Then if you do `article.comments.clear()` then all removed comments will be deleted from the database.

Comment: Indeed, this should work, however, in such a case pony raises an exception: _"ValueError: Attribute Trend[16].location is required"_  from _pony\utils.py", line 126_

Comment: Oops, this is a bug. Turns out, PonyORM does not take `cascade_delete` value into account when removing items from the collection. I'll fix this in few days. Currently as a workaround instead of `location.trends.clear()` you can do `for trend in location.trends: trend.delete()`

Comment: Hi @TomaszPlonka, i fixed the bug and pushed new code to GitHub. It will be part of release PonyORM 0.6.2. Now if `Trend.location` attribute is `Required` then `location.trends.clear()` should delete all previous trends. Also, if you do `locations.trends.remove(t1)`  then `t1` will be deleted.

Comment: Fantastic, great product

Comment: how does this work when you have many to many relationships? where on both sides you have a `Set` relationship